# Easy way to visualize street traffic in a city map in 2D

Tags: dictionary, 2d, visualization, simulation, traffic

I have a couple of data files, one of which is describing a map in terms of a graph with edges (x and y of streets and lanes) between nodes (intersections) and the other one is series of locations of a number of vehicles moving in that map over time. I want to visualize the movement of vehicles in animation with the ability to pause, rewind, or jump to specific points in time. The visuals are to be in their simplest 2D form possible, nothing fancy is necessary ([see this frame created by OpenGL as a sample sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6RMT.jpg)). I am looking for suggestions for any tool, software, package, library that could help. I'm most comfortable with python and there seem to be ways for animating with matplotlib but any other language or product is also acceptable if it makes things easier and faster.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mature JavaScript-based traffic simulation framework that you may want to check out: https://github.com/movsim/traffic-simulation-de

It's using JavaScript's canvas 2D API for visualization.